# How to calculate the building coverage ratio (BCR) if buildings overlap with two or more land parcels?

Tags: postgis, query, splitting

I use the following SQL query to calculate the BCR of land parcels in PostGIS:

```
CREATE VIEW public.v_bcr AS SELECT
    land_parcels.gid,
    ST_Collect(buildings.geom)::geometry(Multipolygon, /*SRID*/) AS geom,
    ST_Area(ST_Collect(buildings.geom))/(ST_Area(land_parcels.geom)/100) AS bcr
FROM land_parcels, buildings
WHERE ST_Within(ST_Snap(buildings.geom, land_parcels.geom, 1e-5), ST_Snap(land_parcels.geom, buildings.geom, 1e-5))
GROUP BY land_parcels.gid;
```

This query considers two possible cases:

1. Land parcels contain more than one building.
2. Vertices of buildings are located at segments of land parcels.

[image]

But sometimes buildings overlap with two or more land parcels. Is there any way to split these buildings in the query posted above?

[image]

Comment: You could add an ST_Intersection to break up the building polys.  You could then return the area of the building in each parcel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to jbalk I've found a query that solves my problem. I have to split the buildings in a subquery using ST_Intersection().

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_bcr AS SELECT
    row_number() over() AS gid,
    ST_Collect(subquery.geom)::geometry(Multipolygon, /*SRID*/) AS geom,
    ST_Area(ST_Collect(subquery.geom))/(ST_Area(land_parcels.geom)/100) AS bcr
FROM
(SELECT
    (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(buildings.geom, land_parcels.geom))).geom AS geom
FROM public.land_parcels, public.buildings
WHERE ST_Intersects(buildings.geom, land_parcels.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(buildings.geom, land_parcels.geom)
) AS subquery, public.land_parcels
WHERE ST_Within(ST_Snap(subquery.geom, land_parcels.geom, 1e-5), ST_Snap(land_parcels.geom, subquery.geom, 1e-5))
GROUP BY land_parcels.gid;
```