# QGIS Joining Parcel Polygons where overlay of Building Footprints crosses Multiple Parcels

Tags: qgis, polygon, parcel, footprint

**QGIS 3.4.4**

**Polygon Layer 1 = Land Parcels**

**Polygon Layer 2 = Building Footprints**

Some buildings exist across several parcels. How can I use the information in **Layer 2** (*red in the image below*) to identify and join all parcel polygons in **Layer 1** (*black in the image below*) that are beneath the same building?

And, in the process, assign the data from **Layer 2** (*area, height, elevation*) to the newly joined parcel polygon?

I realize that I could probably assign the Object ID from **Layer 2** to **Layer 1** and sort -- but I feel like that might not work where multiple buildings are involved.

[image: Example]

Comment: The multiple buildings is tricky.  Would you have this situation: three parcels side by side and two buildings, building A spans parcels 1 and 2, building B spans parcel 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, that's possible -- the data set is very large (750k+ parcel polygons and 2 million building footprint polygons). Maybe that's the 2.0 version. For right now, I'd be happy to solve 1.0 -- that is one building over multiple parcels

Comment: your higlighted example buildng is quite simple but .. how would like the other cases to be treated ? at the bottom of your picture you have some builiding **intersecting 4 parcels** ... doing a SQL Query doing what you want is not too hard ... but what for these special cases ? you should play with an **'overlapping ratio'** to solve these complicated situations ...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How would you do it for the highlighted example without going the ObjectID/tabular data route?

Comment: For the simple example, you can use `join attributes by location` to assign the Building ID to the parcels that it overlaps. Then `dissolve` the parcel layer based on the Building ID. Not sure if this is the most processing-efficient method; I recommend testing on a subset of the data first.

Comment: This looks like the right track: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221834/how-to-calculate-the-building-coverage-ratio-bcr-if-buildings-overlap-with-two